# How to make a foreach request in Apollo GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, apollo, prismic.io

I have a blog in javascript and I'm using Apollo GraphQL to save my data. I intend to make a list with six posts of all categories. Like this:

```
[
  technology: [
    post1,
    post2,
    ...
  ],
  cook: [
    post1,
    post2,
    ...
  ],
  ...
]
```

But I couldn't. I thought in take all categories's id's and make a big request, like this:

```
{
  firstCategory: allPosts(where: {category: "firstId"}, first: 6) {
    ...fields
  }

  secondCategory: allPosts(where: {category: "secondId"}, first: 6) {
    ...fields
  }
}
```

But if I add a new category, I must change my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass categories [queried earlier] as variables, like:

```
query posts($firstCat: String, $secondCat: String, $limit: Int) {
  firstCategory: allPosts(where: {category: $firstCat}, first: $limit) {
    ...fields
  }
  secondCategory: allPosts(where: {category: $secondCat}, first: $limit) {
    ...fields
  }
}
```

variables:

```
{
  "firstCat": "technology",
  "secondCat": "cook",
  "limit": 6
}
```

**Of course, it's still limited to n prepared aliases.**

**Building dynamic aliases are possible but not adviced - [source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjMs-WO683uAhXS_CoKHWQhC88QFjADegQIBRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fapollographql%2Fgraphql-tag%2Fissues%2F202)** ... AST tools should be used as gluing strigs (directly or using literals) is considered as **abusing GraphQL**.

You can also destructure this component, multiple `<Category name="technology" />` components with their own internal query (use `props.name` as category filter variable). This will make separate requests.

For speed and SEO purposes you can use gatsby (amount of separate requests doesn't matter ... up to some scale) - but (as all static generators) it requires rebuild/redeploy on changes.

**Good API** should let you query for tags and related posts inside each of them (sorted by any criteria; ... and author inside [and his posts] ... etc - it's a standard GraphQL feature).